# Why can't I log onto Stack Overflow with my redirected OpenID?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, google

I'm trying to login to Stack Overflow with OpenID and I am receiving an error from Google saying "Request-URI Too Large". Is this an issue with Google or an issue with Stack Overflow's implementation of OpenID?

My OpenID url: http://54.org/thomas

```
 <link rel="openid.server" href="https://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g"/>
 <link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://blog.thomasandcarrie.com/"/>
```

The URL

Comment: This question should probably move to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: As Brett mentioned, questions regarding the inner workings of SO belong on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: So I tried switching my provider to yahoo (and to openid2) but the login page continues to send me to blogger to login. I even deleted my original openid tags and I still have the same problem. Now when I arrived at meta.stackoverflow.com and try to sign in with my openid url it sends me to yahoo but when i get back to meta.stackoverflow.com it says that my openID url is https://me.yahoo.com/a/gwn.f080w51ozxy_3scmtxshjl8t instead of 54.org/thomas

Comment: @Thomas - if you link your SO and MSO accounts you'll regain ownership of this question

Comment: @ChrisF bah, now I have two SO accounts because I couldn't login to my original SO account. I tried to link my SMO but it linked with my original SO account. I'm starting to get very annoyed with OpenID, have you guys thought about using Facebook Connect as an alternative?

Comment: @Thomas - e-mail team@stackoverflow.com and they'll help you sort the accounts out. I use MyOpenID and haven't had any problems (famous last words). BTW, I'm just a user of the sites, but Facebook Connect didn't exist when SO was created.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks for the email. I realize that facebook connect is very new, but it is essentially a more fleshed out implementation of the openID concept. It wouldnt' have to be a replacement just an alternative.

Comment: The biggest problem with OpenID is that it doesn't provide a clean way for Facebook's CEO to steal your credentials...

Comment: @Shog9 that doesn't even make sense, the whole point is that there are no individual site credentials. The biggest problems with OpenID are a)it's difficult for an average user to understand b)there are a myriad of providers and implementations that can lead to problems like the one I'm having where my account can only be retrieved by intervention of an administrator. OpenID gets an A+ for proof of concept and a C- for implementation. I only suggest Facebook as an additional service.

Comment: Heh, I was joking! Big story on Slashdot earlier about Mark Zuckerberg apparently grabbing user credentials in order to access their accounts on other sites... But this was supposedly done early in the life of the site; I'm sure he doesn't have time to go messing with every user's off-site accounts anymore, given Facebook's current popularity! ;-)

Comment: haha, i missed that one. Zuckerberg is his own worst enemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(redirection is not relevant, it's the "long URL" and Blogger OpenID which are the relevant bits here.)

This is a bug in Blogger's OpenID support which is documented here

http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/144

I contacted [Andrew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/46926/andrew-arnott) and he's planning to implement a workaround in [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/) but it'll take a few days to get implemented on our end.

Until then, there is a workaround:

http://blog.nerdbank.net/2010/03/how-to-upgrade-your-blogger-openid-to.html

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue. Unfortunately I do not have control over this question.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me (although it's *myopenid*):

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />  
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://kle.myopenid.com/" />
```